# Как печатать с помощью Java(принтер)

Tags: java, pdf, принтер

Есть массив byte(byte[] array) - в этом массиве находится уже готовый PDF файл. 
Т.е. если его записать как файл - то открывается читаемый PDF и я все вижу.

Но вопрос такой : Как распечатать данный массив в том виде , в котором он есть?
Т.е. без сохранения его ка документа на диск, а чисто распечатать ?
Можно попробовать через   `File tempFile = File.createTempFile("cdekPrintOrders", ".pdf");`, потом на выходе поставить    `tempFile.deleteOnExit();` Но как передать его чтобы не вызывать доп. окна  можно?

Comment: Есть большая разница между массивом байт pdf-файла и массивом байт задания печати. Придётся преобразовать, а потом воспользоваться пакетом [javax.print](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html) для вывода на принтер.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, можете еще подсказать пожалуйста, а как вызвать обычное диалоговое окно печати ОС(в данном случае интересует Windows) пример - http://radiomaster.ru/cad/matlab/glava5/17.gif.

Интересно , можно ли это сделать без swing? Просто вызвать окно.

Comment: Если нужно вызвать **окно**, то придётся задействовать оконную библиотеку - Swing или JavaFX.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо.